# getelementbyid returns null in asp server page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms

I am trying to grab a form inside a usercontrol with asp server pages.

I have tried multiple things but without luck.

```
<tr id="trManageAddress" runat="server" visible="false">
    <td>
          <form id="addressForm">...form here....</form>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            var addressForm = document.getElementById("addressForm");
            if (addressForm == null)
                alert("null");
            else
                alert("good");
        </script>
    </td>
</tr>
```

However the alert keeps returning with null. 
I don't see what I am doing wrong here?

**Note** Before testing, an other piece of code sets trManageAddress visible to true.

**Edit** I got noticed I shouldn't include a second form but use the form in the master page, the issue is solved now I can successful access the masterpage form.

Comment: Inspect the DOM and make sure the element really has that ID.

Comment: Felix is on the right track. When you are trying to get the ID of an element in ASP.NET, the ID on the client is not the same as the ID on the server. The client side ID often has the name of the master page or parent control etc. To get around this, change the client ID of the control to "Static", ex: `ClientIdMode="Static"`. You might also change this in the web.config so you don't have to do it for every control. Alternatively, you can use inline ASPX markup to embed the client ID in the JavaScript, but that's just messy to me.

Comment: If the form has the `runat="server"` attribute set, then the form's id will be mangled by .NET.  You might need to use the `ClientID` property or use class or name based selector.

Comment: You should either post your edit as an answer (and then accept that as the answer), or delete this question. Leaving the fact that you've solved it in the question is a little confusing ;)

Comment: I would if I could however the answer box is hidden from this question.